# How to send AWS templated email from cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ses

I am trying to send templated email with command:

```bash
aws ses send-templated-email --source "temp@gmail.com" --destination "ToAddresses=example@gmail.com" --template-data "{ "firstName": "temp", "lastName": "temp" }" --cli-input-json file://temp.json
```

but I do not know why I get the following error

```
Invalid type for parameter Template, value: {'TemplateName': 'temp', 'SubjectPart': 'Greetings!', 'HtmlPart': '<h3>Dear {{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h3>', 'TextPart': ''}, type: <class 'dict'>, valid types: <class 'str'>
```

The template file content is exactly like this

```json
{
    "Template": {
        "TemplateName": "temp",
        "SubjectPart": "Greetings!",
        "HtmlPart": "<h3>Dear {{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h3>",
        "TextPart": ""
    }
}
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong. How it should be correcltly done with `send-templated-email` command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the template first with `aws ses create-template`. You can't specify the template at runtime. After you create the template, you would reference the data like this:

`aws ses send-templated-email --cli-input-json file://template-values.json`

With `template-values.json` looking something like:

```json
{
  "Source": "<temp@gmail.com>",
  "Template": "temp",
  "Destination": {
    "ToAddresses": ["example@gmail.com"]
  },
  "TemplateData": "{ \"firstName\":\"temp\", \"lastName\": \"temp\" }"
}
```

[AWS Ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-personalized-email-api.html)